# Is it possible to have one git repository for different folders?

Tags: git

I have the following folders on my computer:

> /home/user/git/eclipse-project
>
> /home/user/eagle/eagle-project

The Eclipse Project and the Eagle Project belong to the same task and I have one remote git repository at my university where i shall upload the code. How is it possible to upload the code to the university-git like

> /university-git/eclipse-project
>
> /university-git/eagle-project

without changing the folder structure on my computer (eagle needs the files where they are, and i do not want to move the eclipse project into  my eagle workspace)

Comment: Can you use symlinks?

Comment: Yes, i could, but actually i dont really want any mixing of the two folders on my computer...

Comment: Still, it's by far the easiest way. Create the folders in the Git repository, and create links where you want them.

Answer (score 0):

As far i understood that you just need to create:

- either different branches on same git repository or
- create different remote repositories.

Then you can merge changes from one branch/repository to another then you can clone from any branch in any local folder.(make sense ?)

Regarding creation of branches/repositories and merging please follow below links:

http://gitref.org/branching/

http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html

Note: Handling via remote repositories is quite difficult for beginners but you can try out :)